# I can't handle this method: Thread.sleep()

Tags: android, multithreading, sleep

I can't handle this method: Thread.sleep() in Android Studio.

I want to fill a 9x9 size TextView with a number every 0.1 seconds.

[image]

And, this is my codes.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView[][] basicCell=new TextView[9][9];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initVar();

        int cnt=0;
        for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<9; j++){
                basicCell[i][j].setText(j+"");
                basicCell[i][j].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                basicCell[i][j].setTextSize(20);
                basicCell[i][j].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                try{
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.d("COUNT", ""+cnt++);
            }
        }
    }

TextView[][] basicCell=new TextView[9][9]
```

All textviews are linked with basicCells.

And, The expected results screen is as follows.

[image]

In the middle of the code,

By inserting

```
try {Thread.sleep (100); }

catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace();}
```

I tried to get the number one every 0.1 seconds ...

When you run the app, it stays on for a few seconds and the numbers come up at once.

I took a look at the log,

```
Log.d ("COUNT", "" + cnt ++);
```

In log chat, the logs are working hard,

The screen is in a state of jamming for a few seconds,

Since cnt is 80, the numbers are displayed on the screen at once.

I thought it was an emulator lag, so I ran it on my smartphone, and the result is the same.

I do not know what the problem is.

Is there a way to see the results as intended?

Comment: You should read about UI/Main thread ... basically you are blocking it ... so there will be no screen update until you release it. movie your loop to another thread and from it post UI's operation back to main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look at the official guide for Processes and Threads. Your code is being executed on the main thread, but you can't just make it sleep, because it will freeze your UI. Also, onCreate is executed in order to create your activity, so you won't be able to update your UI just by sleeping the thread in onCreate, because Android will wait until onCreated is executed, then it will show your UI.

You need to create an AsyncTask. Please, read here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Answer (score 0):

`setText(...)`, `setTextColor(...)`, etc. don't change anything on the screen.  They only change values recorded in the `TextView` objects to which you apply them.  The framework will then ask the `TextView` objects to render themselves to the screen *after* your function has returned.

I don't know Android, so I don't know the proper names of things, but if you want things on the screen to change over time (i.e., if you want to *animate* your display), then you'll need to set up some kind of a timer task---a callback function that gets called periodically.  Each time it gets called, it should change one thing (e.g., update one cell), and then it should return so that the cell will have a chance to render itself to the screen.